# software RAID array not starting in initramfs on Debian

Tags: debian, raid, boot, mdadm, initramfs

One of my Debian servers (kernel 2.6.30-AMD64) refuses to start the software RAID array that houses the root partition in initramfs. It dumps me with a busybox console. When I follow the necessary steps to continue booting it works fine (start the array with mdadm -A and then have LVM scan the volumes with pvscan and then vgchange -ay).

I've tried starting with boot options rootdelay=10 to no avail.

Also I've updated the initramfs and unpacked it to inspect whether it really tries to assemble the raid array (it does).

Output before dumping to console :

```
mount: mounting none on /dev failed: No such device
W: devtmpfs not available, falling back to tpmfs for /dev
```

and then some lvm messages saying it can't find the volumes holding the root partitions.

Does anybody have a clue how I could fix this?

Comment: have you changed the partition IDs to RAID autodetect? (`set 1 raid on` in `parted`)

Comment: yes, well, I didn't change them, they were already set on creation. Under 'Flags' in parted it says raid on all partitions that need to be assembled.

Comment: Do you have your RAID described in /etc/mdadm.conf?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create /etc/mdadm.conf and possibly rebuild initramfs. Check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/277085/linux-fails-to-reassemble-raid-array-after-disk-upgrade/277098#277098) for details.

Comment: yes, I have the /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf (this being Debian) and it's correct and I did update the initramfs and checked it and it's correct. I can also see that the initramfs 'knows' it's correct, because I can assemble with mdadm --assemble --scan (in initramfs shell).

Answer (score 1):

For starting server by hand, please try:

```
(initramfs) mdadm /dev/md0 -A /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
[...]
(initramfs) mdadm /dev/md1 -A /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2
[...]
(initramfs) mdadm /dev/md2 -A /dev/sda3 /dev/sdb3
[...]
```

and so on, all of your md partitions.

If you have LVM, go on with:

```
(initramfs) vgchange -ay
  3 logical volume(s) in volume group "pve" now active
```

then simply type:

```
(initramfs) exit
```

and if all is fine, your system will boot.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, with duplicate name on mdadm.conf

I fix on the following way, thanks to user130370 solution.
[initramfs]mdadm --examine --scan > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
[initramfs]mdadm -q --assemble --scan --run
[initramfs]exit

rebot automatically

from the system as first

#update-initramfs -u