# Linux fails to reassemble RAID array after disk upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, software-raid

I have an Ubuntu (9.10) machine with 4 SATA disks. Each disk is partitioned identically, with the first few gigabytes set aside for a RAID 1 array (`/dev/md0`) for the boot volume, and the remainder set aside for RAID 5 (`/dev/md1`).

Recently, I upgraded to larger drives by repeatedly failing and removing a drive, replacing it with the larger one, partitioning it, and rebuilding onto it, per the instructions [here](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Growing#Extending_an_existing_RAID_array). This all completed successfully.

However, the first time I reboot after upgrading, Ubuntu kicks me out to an initfs shell, claiming it can't find the root device. On checking `/proc/mdstat`, I discover that it's somehow assembled the entire drives (`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` etc) into a single RAID 5 volume under `/dev/md1`, instead of assembling the partitions into their own arrays. Doing `mdadm --stop /dev/md1; mdadm --assemble --scan` fixes it, and both volumes are assembled correctly (and mount without issues).

What's going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `/etc/mdadm.conf` with proper configuration for your array. Even though Linux kernel can detect and assemble mdadm arrays automatically, sometimes it does funny things. Having `/etc/mdadm.conf` eliminates the uncertainty. Here is how mine looks like:

```
DEVICE  /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
ARRAY   /dev/md0 metadata=0.90 UUID=b8fdfd55:524cecb2:2d164f4f:84bee133
```

The ARRAY line comes from output of this command:

```
mdadm --examine --scan
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since it's halting in the initrd, I presume this isn't going to be able to read the updates if I just modify the files. Is there something I can do to have the updated mdadm.conf reflected in the initrd, other than editing it by hand?

Comment: Doing as you suggested (only the devices line needed updating) worked, after running `sudo update-initramfs -u`. Thanks!

Comment: Good job. I haven't been using it with boot devices, so you taught me something new :-)